# Inno setup script in jenkins - version as external variable

Tags: jenkins, inno-setup

In my script I'm using `#define version '1.2.3.45678';` and further in

```
[Setup]
AppVersion={#version}
```

and

`WizardForm.Caption := CustomMessage('WelcomeTitle') + ' - ' + ExpandConstant('{#version}');`

and few more.

I'd like to run the script in jenkins where `version` has to be user's (my) input.
But I've no idea how to smuggle such external variable into the script (if even possible).

Sure I can change the `version` manualy before running the script, but the script is in SVN repo and not all jenkins users have access to the repo.

So far only solution seems to be to let jenkins have dedicated SVN account and commit the user's input before running the script (didn't tested yet).

Comment: Are you intending to have Jenkins run some type of script that will just modify the Inno script and substitute a new value for the version? Or what did you have in mind?

Comment: Indeed, it's not really clear what you mean by *input*. Can you show us how do you imagine you will be providing the *input*? + Side note: The `{#version}` is not a *Inno Setup constant*. So calling `ExpandConstant` is noop. Simple `'{#version}'` instead of `ExpandConstant('{#version}')` will achieve the same.

Comment: In jenkins pipeline page we've confirured a text input field. Entered text (SVN revision number) is used as parameter. Before starting iss script the job copies Src content from SVN by the revision number. Next reads full version of Src\foo\bar\myApp.exe and uses it instead of `#define version '1.2.3.45678';`.

Comment: Src content will be added or updated just before runnig the script via some batch script. So I can determine version of Src\foo\bar\myApp.exe on code section. I'll test it and update / close the question.

Comment: Solutions don't go in edits to the question; if you found one, please post it as an answer and click the checkmark next to it to indicate to readers that it is your chosen solution.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple solution:

```
#define version GetFileVersion("Src\myDir\myApp.exe");
```